# Lightning Component SVG Not Rendering in Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

Using Community Builder, I have an svg component that's not properly rendering an icon (using SLDS 1.2.2).  I've followed the docs exactly as written for the components:

my outer-component that I am using on the Community Builder page:

```
<aura:component controller="MyInvestmentServices"
                implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
                access="global">
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS0122/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" />
    <span class="slds-icon__container slds-icon-standard-approval">
      <c:svg class="slds-icon--large" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS0122/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account" />
    </span>
</aura:component>
```

My "svg" component follows the exact syntax (copy/pasted) from here: [SVG Lightning Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/project/slds-lightning-components-workshop/slds-lc-4)

However, when I load my page I'm getting a 404 error for the symbol.svg resource.

[image]

I added the tags to expose the svg component to the community, and I'm not sure what else could be causing the error.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just experimented and it successfully renders once you publish the community

[image]

I think since community builder gets previewed from different domain ,this seems like a bug to me in the builder .I will bring this to attention to SFDC community product team but rest assured once you publish community it appears just fine.

Comment: Did you also experience it not rendering in preview mode?

Comment: @Jason yes .Since preview is rendered from different domain ,it sounds like bug to me

Comment: It looks like this is happening in Production now.  The same icon above has finally been pushed to Production, & the published site isn't showing the icon.  Getting the same console error as before.