# SVG Not Rendering in Community (AGAIN)

Tags: lightning, community-builder

[My original question here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111217/lightning-component-svg-not-rendering-in-community) was in a sandbox environment, and we determined that the SVG's wouldn't render in community builder, however once published the icons showed up as required.

Now I've got the same community in Production, and Published, and I'm seeing the same error again - this time the published site is showing the error as well.

I'm assuming this is a bug?  Is there anyone else seeing this, or does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Do you have SLDS static resource uploaded in prod?

Comment: Yes, and the css files are loading properly.  it's just the symbols.svg file that's not wanting to load.

Comment: It is not loading in any browser or any specific browser? We just went live and svg icons are working fine for us. We had issues in IE browser but there is a workaround.

Comment: not working in any browser.

Comment: Ok. I just created a simple Lightning App in my Developer Edition sandbox(Summer 16) with SVG icon and it is working fine. Do you want me to share the code? Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding community name in the URL mentioned in svg component.

For ex. /CommunityName/resource/SLDS/asset...

Answer (score 0):

Did we make sure, that if the SVG is being used as a static resource then the cache control is set to 'public'. If you are using change sets, it may set it back to the default 'private'. In private, it will throttle any png/svg resource from loading for guest users who are visiting it.